# Хочу реализовать ввод фамилии и имя ,пробовал через input.Только ничего не работает

Tags: python, ооп

```py
class Info():
    def __init__(self, name="Info_name", surname="Info_surname"):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def Start(self):
        print("Меня зовут " + self.name + "а моя фамилия " + self.surname)


my_info = Info()
my_info = Info("Максим","ггг")
my_info.Start()
```

Comment: что означает "не работает"? У врача тоже говоришь "что-то болит" и пусть он сам разбирается, что там у тебя болит?

Comment: помогите пожалуйста реализовать input в данном коде

Comment: У вас в коде нет ни одного input. Если его нет, то и работать нечему.

Answer (score -1):

```
class info():
    name = input('Введите имя')
    surname = input('Введите фамилию')

    def Start(name, surname):
        print("Меня зовут " +name + " а моя фамилия " + surname)

info.Start(name=info.name, surname=info.surname)
```

Comment: если ответ решает проблему, нажмите галочку

Comment: спасибо.Не могу поставить оценку так как репутация не такая большая

Comment: Лучше сделайте экземпляр класса. Использовать поля самого класса, да ещё и передавать их методу класса, когда они у него у самого есть - как-то неаккуратно выглядит

Comment: @max, автор вопроса может отметить ответ принятым, для этого нужно поставить галку слева от ответа. Галку, не стрелку вверх.

Answer (score -2):

Вот так.

```
class Info():
    # конструктор, собирает экземпляр класса из переменных. По сути, функция, срабатывающая при создании экземпляра класса
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def start(self):
        print("Меня зовут " + self.name + ", а моя фамилия " + self.surname)

my_info = Info("Максим","ггг")
my_info.start()
```

Comment: Но где же собственно `input`? )

Comment: А input() можно применить при создании экземпляра класса - строку my_info = Info("Максим","ггг") поменять на my_info = Info(input("введите имя),input("введите фамилию"))

Comment: Ну так и добавьте это в код. Вопрос то про `input` именно был